# Should I look worried by problems on the workplace?

Tags: teamwork, work-time, colleagues, italy

I always look relaxed, even when there are troubles, I look like a zen master, seeing my worried face is extremely rare.

I have a coworker which is always worried of everything, usually we are ok but sometimes, he gets really angry with me, because he says that he can't handle the impression that "I don't give a fuck about anything".

Obviously, this is his own point of view, I'm just confident, if a program has a bug, I will check the problem, fix everything, test it and release the fixes.

I really don't get the needs of his "always worried" lifestyle, and I ask to myself if he's right when he says that I should look worried when something bad happens.

From my point of view, an employee who can always be relaxed, cold and ready to think, maybe is the best thing that an employer can look for.

Should I look worried by problems on the workplace?

Comment: What's the question here?  People handle problems and stress in different and unique ways.

Comment: Yes, the question is if he's right when he says that I should be like him on a workplace. He says that my attitude is wrong at all

Comment: Is the question how to handle your colleague (answerable) or with whom we side (opinion-based and off-topic)

Comment: Nope, the question is from the side of an employer which reaction should i have

Comment: @MarcoSalerno are you talking about dev/test environment issues, production application issues/bugs, or something like network/server failures on production? And has your boss ever made a remark about this matter?

Comment: Production bugs, nope, nobody does, I'm that kind of worker which does every task asked

Comment: I think you should purchase a Scream Ghost Face Mask https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=hc7YWsvwEenP5gKJupSAAg&q=Scream+Ghost+Face+Mask&oq=Scream+Ghost+Face+Mask&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1l3.890.890.0.2129.2.1.0.0.0.0.346.346.3-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.344.0...0.-Wq8O8NpoBk and keep it in your workplace. When you colleague reports a problem, hold it momentarily in front of your face. As soon as he has seen and reacted to it, put it away and work the problem in your usual style.

Comment: Bobby McFerrin wrote a book titled "Don't Worry, Be Happy" (after the top hit record of the same title), where he explains exactly why your attitude is the right one. Worrying doesn't help, solving problems helps. Worrying just drags everyone down and stops them from solving problems.

Answer (score 4):

Different people react to stress differently.  Some people remain calm no matter what  which is often a good trait. (see that pilot that landed the plane when part of the engine came off recently. Would you really have wanted her to be panicky if you were on the plane?) So your reaction is just fine and normal.

However, apparently your colleague does not operate that way. Perhaps he gets more worried than you because something really bad happens in the past  and perhaps it partly happened because someone else was unconcerned and didn't do his part of the job. Sometimes, in order to make the workplace more effective, you need to bend a little to help out others. I am not saying look worried or act panicky, but...

Is it possible that you can verbally express concern without looking worried? Something to indicate that you do care if the bug gets fixed and that you are getting right to fixing it?

Comment: Usually i answer "stay calm, i'm fixing it!" but he still gets angry. It's important to say that I'm not someone who makes always-buggy-code

Comment: Skip the stay calm part. That is fairly insulting even when, maybe even especially when, the person is not calm. And discuss with your boss, maybe he can get this person to leave you alone when you have said you are fixing something.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the **right idea and attitude**.  Why stress out over things that are out of your control?  I tend to offer up the advise of being aware of what is going on at the company level and more directly between you and your manager.

For instance, from the *bigger picture*

1. Is the company making its numbers?
2. Are people being laid off?
3. Are raises being given?

If these things are all positive, then from a *company* perspective you are good to go.  From a more direct perspective, specifically **yours**, you should know or ask these things of **your manager**:

1. Are you satisfied with my work?
2. Is there something I could do better?
3. Is my attitude in line?

If the answers from these two perspectives are positive, then in general there is nothing to be concerned about.  There are other factors of course, but these guidelines should take care of most case, from your perspective.

Don't let someone else's un-necessary stress impact you.  Do your job and forge ahead in a positive manner as you have been.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a family with a history of stress related heart conditions, I make sure to minimise the amount of stress in my life.

This approach has been a benefit to me and my employers. I once worked in an environment where most of my immediate colleagues threw stress temper-tantrums for many reasons, from the office being to warm, their computers being too slow and not being cc'd into an email.

Being stressed at small things is simply childish. Being able to work complex tasks under difficult circumstances whilst being professional is something an employer will value.